# SVAR model with trend variables, can you please help me

Tags: time-series, vector-autoregression, trend

I am working on SVAR model that contains four variables, log of oil price, log of GDP, log of the effective exchange rate, and inflation. My analysis focuses on short-term (Cholesky Identification) and long-term (Blanchard & Quah(1989) Identification). According to The Augmented Dickey-Fuller (ADF) test, all my variables are not stationary in level, and according to Phillips-Perron (PP), inflation and log of REER are stationary in level, but the rest are not. However, I found also that three variables have a deterministic trend (oil, GDP, REER), and inflation has a stationary trend. This is not surprising because I have Macroeconomic variables.
I detrend the variables (residuals) before I run the SVAR model, and the results are reasonable. The model passed all post-estimation tests.
Do what I did the correct approach?
Do I need to test anything like the cointegration test?

Comment: Did you estimate the model in levels (after detrending) or first differences? If the latter, you might have missing cointegration. That would amount to an omitted variable bias in some or all of your equations.

Comment: I have estimated the model in level after I detrend all the variable. Does the interpretation change in this situation?